# UIView not triggering action in corresponding controller

Tags: swift, firebase, model-view-controller, view, uiview

I have a LoginController which displays a LoginView. When the user enters email & password a new ViewController should appear called cockpitController of class CockpitController. I don't use a storyboard.
Problem: When I hit the login button, the loginController don't seems to receive the action.
The `@objc func loginButtonClicked()` should call `func login` in the `loginController`. What I'm missing here.

**LoginController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    var loginView: LoginView { return self.view as! LoginView }

    var homeController: HomeController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = LoginView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        loginView.setupViews()
    }

    var cockpitController: CockpitController?

    func login(email: String, password: String) {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
           guard error == nil else {
            //   ...
              return
            }

            self.present(self.cockpitController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

***LoginView***

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        setupViews()
    }

    var loginController: LoginController?

    let userEmailTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return textField
    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return textField
    }()

    let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .highlighted)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(loginButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let signUpButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Creat a Account", for: .normal)

        return button
    }()

    @objc func loginButtonClicked() {

        let email = userEmailTextField.text
        let password = passwordTextField.text

        self.loginController?.login(email: email!, password: password!)

    }

    func setupViews() {

        //... addSubviews
        //... constraints
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `loginController` of the `loginView`.

```
override func loadView() {

    self.view = LoginView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    loginView.loginController = self
    loginView.setupViews()
}
```

Tip: Also, modify `loginController` in `loginView` as `weak var` to avoid reference cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more proposal!
You need to change this line:

- `var loginController: LoginController?`
- **To this:**
- `weak var loginController: LoginController?`

That will help you to not get a strong reference and memory leaks.